# Cannot save sharepoint page with my custom webpart (with asp.net validation controls)!

Tags: visual-web-part, validation

I am using sp2010. I have created a visual webpart in Visual Studio 2010. In this webpart I have created a sort of contact form with fields and a button. I have deployed this webpart to my sp site and add the webpart to a page. I can see the webpart, but if I try to save or check in the page I got this warning:

Error: This page contains content or formatting that is not valid. You can find more information in the affected sections.  Important StatusStatus: Checked out and editable.

The reason of this warning is my asp.net validation are executed when I try to save the page. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your validation controls (and your button) should specify a validation group.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have already specified a validationgroup on all my controls in my custom form builded in a visual webpart programmatically(VS2012). Also my button. So what do I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that particular user has permission  in list

Comment: Please provide more details.